# Div tags inside of Div tags not work in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome

This seems incredibly simple but I have no idea why I can't put a div tag inside of a container div tag as it will not show up in Firefox or Chrome properly, *but* it works in IE6...??? Code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS: style.css

```
body {
    background:white;
    font-family: sans-serif;

}
#container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:960px;
    background:#e3e3e3;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#nav {
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    float:left;
    width: 400px;
    height:100px;
    background:white;
    border:1 px solid black;
}
```

It's as if the container is not expanding with the DIV tag inside of it..what gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common issue people face with CSS. Whenever you float something, it's parent collapses as you are seeing. You can work around it in the following ways:

1. set an explicit height on the container
2. put overflow:hidden or overflow:auto on the container
3. use the clearfix hack: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

I find #2 to be the easiest and best in most cases. Use #3 when overflow:hidden/auto has an undesirable side effect.

Comment: wow thanks for this, so simple I forget the basic things, I just started into web development, I guess I missed some basics tricks!

Comment: It's a strange aspect of CSS, once you understand this and a couple other quirks, you'll be unstoppable :)

Answer (score 4):

It is because the #nav div is floated left. Floated elements are just that--floating, and have no height unless something anchors the box below it by clearing the floats.

```
 .clear { clear: both }
```

and add a div below the floating div to clear it.

```
 <div id="container">
     <div id="nav">
         <p>Hello</p>
     </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
```

See this SO question for a very detailed answer on clearfixes: [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Comment: This works, but I find the extra markup to be undesirable, especially when alternative methods exist that do not require it.

Comment: Agreed. I edited my answer with a link to a question concerning the best clearfix hack.

Answer (score 0):

Do `overflow: hidden` for `#container`.

This is one known limitation of floating.

- Before: http://jsfiddle.net/N669N/
- After: http://jsfiddle.net/N669N/1/